# Select post and concatenating all categories it belongs to

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, group-concatenation

I have 3 DB tables

```
POSTS
+----------+----------+----------+
| id       |  title   |  content |
+----------+----------+----------+

CATEGORIES
+----------+----------+
| id       |  title   |
+----------+----------+

POSTS_CATEGORIES
+----------+----------+--------------+
| id       |  post_id |  category_id |
+----------+----------+--------------+
```

Now lets say I have the following posts:

`id=1, title=birds` and it belongs to category 1 and 4

`id=2, title=apple` and it does not belong to any categories

My Query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.content
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p_c.category_id ORDER BY p_c.category_id ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS categories
FROM posts_categories AS p_c, posts as p
WHERE p.id = 1 AND p.id = p_c.post_id
GROUP BY p_c.post_id
```

This query works for `id=1` but when a post does not have any categories, like `id=2` it won't find anything. I've tried to modify this a bit, but I always end up with no results or all the fields as null when I'm looking for `id=2`

I know I could get around this with 2 queries, but was trying to do it with one query. I'm using mysql 5.5.27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get all posts and a list of categories (If no categories, then 'None')

```
SELECT
    p.id, p.title, p.content,
    IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(p_c.category_id
    ORDER BY p_c.category_id ASC SEPARATOR ','),'None') category
FROM
    posts p
    LEFT JOIN posts_categories p_c ON p.id = p_c.post_id
    LEFT JOIN categories c ON p_c.category_id = c.id
WHERE
    p.id = 1
GROUP BY
    p.id
;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I'm not looking for all posts, just 1 post with all categories associated with it, regardless if the categories are empty or not.

Comment: Added `WHERE p.id = 1` to the query...